# How to enable DataGridView cell boarder highlighting on selection VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have two DataGridViews on a single windows form, `dgvIncome` and `dgvCashFlow`. When I run the program (acting as a user) and select a cell in dgvIncome, it highlights that cell's border to indicate the cell is selected.

[image]

However, when I do the same thing with dgvCashFlow, there is no border and it appears as though nothing is selected (I have checked, the cell is being selected).
[image]

Is there any way that I can make this second DataGridViews behave the same as the first one?

This is the only code I have written that formats the second DataGridView. Most of it is just for adding items from a text file to a ComboBox Column

```
Public Sub FormatCFS(ByVal dgvTableToFormat As DataGridView)

        Dim cbcCategory As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = dgvTableToFormat.Columns(0)
        Dim sreReader As StreamReader
        Dim strFormatDirectory As String

        strFormatDirectory = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Program Files\Finance Manager\Files\Format\" & Today.Year).OrderByDescending(Function(f) New FileInfo(f).LastWriteTime).First()

        sreReader = File.OpenText(strFormatDirectory)

        Dim bolType As Boolean = 0

        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(strFormatDirectory)

            If line = "EXPENSES" Then bolType = 1

            If line <> "INCOMES" And line <> "" And bolType = 0 Then

                cbcCategory.Items.Add(line.Trim())

            ElseIf line <> "EXPENSES" And line <> "INCOMES" And line <> "" Then

                If Not line.Remove(8, line.Length - 8) = "Category" Then cbcCategory.Items.Add(line.Remove(0, 8).Trim())

            End If

        Next

        sreReader.Close()


        'Format Columns
        For Each Column As DataGridViewColumn In dgvTableToFormat.Columns
            Column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            Column.Width = 100
        Next

        dgvTableToFormat.Columns(0).Width = 135
        dgvTableToFormat.Columns(1).ValueType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal")

    End Sub
```

Comment: Are the properties of the two DataGridViews the same ?

Comment: Yes, they are exactly the same. Believe me, I've checked many times. I have since found that if I press tab once a cell is selected in the second datagridview, the selection highlight begins to work as it does with the first datagridview. But this doesn't really solve the problem (I thought it might be helpful for someone on here to know) as I don't expect many end users will use tab to navigate through the datagridview.

Comment: Thanks @BasH for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

This is only partial code. What I did is create a DB and it has two tables IncomeTable and ExpenseTable
I created two DGV dgvIncome and dgvExpense
Both DGV are on the same form See Screen Shot
Here is the code I used to highlight he rows. Not sure that is what you wanted?

```
 Private Sub dgvIncome_CellClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvIncome.CellClick
    selRow = e.RowIndex
    dgvIncome.Rows(selRow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue
    'dgvIncome.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink
End Sub
Private Sub dgvExpense_CellClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvExpense.CellClick
    selRow = e.RowIndex
    dgvExpense.Rows(selRow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
    'dgvIncome.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink
    'Line above changes all the CELLS
End Sub
```

Screen Shot
[image: Highlighted Cells]

**Edit this will highlight only the cell selected**

```
dgvExpense.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue
```

Comment: Thanks @Vector for the suggestion! I'm not worried about colour changes. By my testing, they do not impact this selection border highlighting whether it is done in the design or programmatically or not at all. If you are suggesting that I change the cell colour in order to indicate that it is selected, it's not a bad idea. However, I would prefer to find a way to make it work the way it seems to by default in the other DataGridView.

Comment: @Joel I have another idea Sorry I have not tested this. Write a small test app where you put the two Data Grid Views each on their own container like a groupbox or some other control I do this in JavaFX with other controls. Just a off the wall thought

Comment: Hi @Vector, sorry for the late reply, I've been busy with other priorities lately. I tried putting the data grid views in separate group boxes, but it didn't change anything. Honestly, this problem isn't a massive deal, it would just be nice if it worked. Thanks for all the help, but I don't think this problem is worth putting any more effort towards.

Comment: @Joel No problem with late reply that is why we have notifications Let me try some testing So I understand you have two DGV on one form(Page) and when you select the Income one it highlights the selected row but the same behavior does not work on the CashFlow Why I ask! the screen shot shows the name of CashFlow as Income and Expenses ? I doubt it is a naming issue Could we see some code ?

Comment: Hi @Vector, I'm actually more concerned with the highlighting of the selected cell, not the row. Users will not be required to select rows, but individual cells. "Incomes and Expenses" is not the name of the CashFlow DataGridView, it was just a column header. I'll edit the original post to add the code I use to format it, however, I doubt it will be helpful.

Comment: I've also updated the picture of the DataGridView CashFlows, since I have changed its column headers. I didn't mention it earlier as I doubted it would make a difference.

Comment: @Joel I will edit my answer and only show the code I used to change the Rows that are selected. If you want some of the complete project I can zip it up and put it on my GitHub  account

Comment: Thanks @Vector. As I have mentioned in a previous comment, I do not want to use colour changes to indicate a row being selected. Furthermore, I do not want to show when a row is selected, I want to show when a cell is selected. In the DataGridView Income, a cell is automatically highlighted with an outline by default as shown in my first image. I simply want this to occur in the DataGridView CashFlow, which it does not by default.

Comment: @Joel Little Late but see my Answer I dded an Edited line of code for only the CELL selected NOT the entire Row